# Installed additional RAM, detected by CPUZ but not by the system

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard

I bought 2 additional sticks of RAM for my PC that had 2 existing. The RAM is exactly the same (GSkill Ripjaws V model F4-3200C16D-32GVK) as the original 2, but when I installed it, the system did not detect it. It does not show up in the bios system description and the Windows device specs shows 32GB instead of 64GB. The strange thing is that CPUZ clearly shows 64GB and is able to detect all the details of the new installed RAM. Also I'm using an Asrock Fatal1ty X99X Killer motherboard, which is compatible up to 128GB of RAM.

I'm not sure where to go from here, whether the RAM or motherboard is somehow broken, though strange that CPUZ detects it but the system does not. Any suggestions on if I should return the RAM or if there's something else I should try?

[image]

Comment: Hello! Your question looks like it might be similar to this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1267095/system-does-not-show-all-installed-ram-even-though-cpu-z-detects-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System does not show all installed RAM even though CPU-Z detects it](https://superuser.com/questions/1267095/system-does-not-show-all-installed-ram-even-though-cpu-z-detects-it)